Я делаю рассылку на Python используя TelegramApi, хочу присылать сообщения по номеру телефона, а не по username
Я делаю рассылку на Python используя TelegramApi, хочу присылать сообщения по номеру телефона, а не по username.Использую библиотеку telephone, но я не увидел тут возможности присылать по номеру телефона рассылку, а не по username или userid. Есть какие то варианты решения этой проблемы?

По номеру телефона это как? Просто случайные цифры что ли указывать? А если номер скрыт пользователем?

Ну имею ввиду по номеру телефона в личные сообщения в телеграмме, не по username отсылать сообщение личное, а по номеру телефона. Как это сделать?

Вообще, никак. Нет такого параметра, как номер телефона при отправке сообщения в BotAPI. Бот может только запросить контакты у пользователя и все
